# Executing http in android not working

Tags: java, android, web-services, http

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
            client.execute(request);//it fails at this line
            Log.e("yo", "yo");
        } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Have anyone figured out the problem please as I am experiencing the same issue.
My device is connected to the same network, pasting the URL in browser works however using HTTP doesn't.

Comment: Please write `Error(s)` you are receiving. Moreover, have you added INTERNET permission, if not add the `INTERNET` permission to your manifest file.

You need to add line:`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

try HttpPost method

Declare **INTERNET PERMISSION** IN manfiest file

```
httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(URL);

     HttpResponse res = null;
        try {
            res = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            System.out.println("asa "+res);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Mayur Pipaliya have mentioned to internet connection in the manifest. check the comment.

Comment: Yes, but this question was still lacking an actual answer regarding the permission.

Comment: So then the answer can be added by @Mayur.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive input toward answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it on the same thread as your UI? You have to use separate thread for any network connection to prevent UI Blocking. You need to use AsyncTask in this case; and obviously, android Internet permission is needed.